# importing this sql file to phpmyadmin is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
USE `textplus`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`password` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`email` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`authenticationTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`userKey` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`IP` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`port` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `Index_2` (`username`),
KEY `Index_3` (`authenticationTime`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends`(
`Id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`whoProvideId` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`whoRequestId` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`status` binary(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY(`Id`),
UNIQUE KEY `Index_3` (`whoProvideId`,`whoRequestId`),
KEY `Index_2` (`whoProvideId`,`whoRequestId`,`status`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='whoProvideId is the Id of the users who wish to be friend with' AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages`(
`id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fromWhoId` int(255) NOT NULL ,
`toWhoId` int(9) NOT NULL,
`sendDate` datetime NOT NULL,
`read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`readDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`messageTextLong` longText CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
KEY `id`(`id`),
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=22;
```

Comment: this is the error :   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7' at line 15

Comment: Please add that into your question.

Comment: remove the `,` after the last line in the create clause for instance here: `KEY `Index_3` (`authenticationTime`),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove comma and you are done,

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`password` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`email` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`authenticationTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`userKey` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`IP` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`port` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `Index_2` (`username`),
KEY `Index_3` (`authenticationTime`)  --Remove comma from here
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends`(
`Id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`whoProvideId` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`whoRequestId` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`status` binary(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY(`Id`),
UNIQUE KEY `Index_3` (`whoProvideId`,`whoRequestId`),
KEY `Index_2` (`whoProvideId`,`whoRequestId`,`status`) --Remove comma from here
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='whoProvideId is the Id of the users who wish to be friend with' AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages`(
`id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fromWhoId` int(255) NOT NULL ,
`toWhoId` int(9) NOT NULL,
`sendDate` datetime NOT NULL,
`read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`readDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`messageTextLong` longText CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
KEY `id`(`id`) --Remove comma from here
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=22;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57401d)**